# Is there a way to create super fierce memory leaks?

Tags: c++

I know that a common way to render memory leak is to assign a specific piece of memory address for a variable by new without releasing it. But is there a way to create epic and fierce memory leak that can very quickly force the computer to shutdown?

Comment: `while (true) { static_cast<void>(new int); }`

Comment: "force the computer to shutdown" ? If you can do that with a memory-misbehaving user-space program, your OS is pretty crappy. You can bring things to a pretty sluggish crawl, though. If you really want the wheels to fall off the wagon something kernel-mode will probably be required.

Comment: There is no memory leak that I would ever agree should be considered "epic" or "fierce", and I imagine I'm not the only one who feels that way.

Comment: Everyone has different thoughts and one shouldn't judge another's idea by his standard. Some memory leaks, in my point of view, can be fabulous and cool, even though you and some other people don't agree with me :)

Comment: A question that involves objective criteria, one that doesn't require the reader to figure out what's "epic" to you, is answerable by a larger part of the audience though.

Comment: Readers don't have to agree with the subjective idea, but simply denying it and saying its wrong is obviously superficial, my generous friend. Because whether the idea is good or not is not and will never be objective :) pls, this paragraph is only for communicating and learning purpose. And the adjectives were written by me to describe subjective thoughts. They're not created in order to force the readers to think exactly like me, you may have misunderstood that.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This takes a couple of seconds on my laptop.

```
int main(){
    for(;;){
        int *a=new int[1000];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this :)

Comment: It won't crash any OS but it will force things into swap depending on how your system is configured.

Comment: I don't know about *nix, but on Windows 8/10 it will barely even do that.  The virtual memory isn't committed until the program writes to it, so really all this code does is create a hung process that eats CPU and slowly exhausts its own virtual address space before eventually crashing with `std::bad_alloc`